# Add onClick Event to <tr> in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `<Table />` which gets dynamically popoulated with data from an object array.
I want to add an `onClick` event to the `<TableRow />` so the data in that row can be updated. `onClick` event does not seem to call my `openBookDetails` function.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Update.css';
import Search from '../Search/Search';

const Table = ({ data }) => (
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr class="table-primary">
                <th scope="col">Title</th>
                <th scope="col">Author</th>
                <th scope="col">ISBN</th>
                <th scope="col">No. Of Copies</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {data.map(row => 
                <TableRow key={row.id} row={row} />
            )}

        </tbody>
    </table>
)

const TableRow = ({ row }) => (
     <tr class="table-light" onClick={this.openBookDetails}>
        <th scope="row" >{row.title}</th>
        <td >{row.author}</td>
        <td >{row.isbn}</td>
        <td >24</td>
    </tr>
)


class Update extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            value: '',
            suggestions: [],
            setOfAllBooks: [],
            searchedBooks: []
        };

        this.openBookDetails = this.openBookDetails.bind(this);
        this.setTableData = this.setTableData.bind(this);
    }

    setTableData(searchedBook){
        this.setState({searchedBooks: searchedBook})

        console.log(this.state.searchedBooks)
    }

    openBookDetails(){
        console.log("openBookDetails")
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <Search state={this.state} setTableData={this.setTableData} />
                <Table data={this.state.searchedBooks} />
            </div>

        )
    }
}

export default Update;
```

Comment: You are not passing the `openBookDetails` function to your `Table` component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should send your functions to child component as props.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Update.css';
import Search from '../Search/Search';

const Table = ({ data, action }) => (
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr class="table-primary">
                <th scope="col">Title</th>
                <th scope="col">Author</th>
                <th scope="col">ISBN</th>
                <th scope="col">No. Of Copies</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {data.map(row => 
                <TableRow key={row.id} row={row} action={action} />
            )}

        </tbody>
    </table>
)

const TableRow = ({ row, action }) => (
    <tr class="table-light" onClick={action()}>
        <th scope="row" >{row.title}</th>
        <td >{row.author}</td>
        <td >{row.isbn}</td>
        <td >24</td>
    </tr>
)


class Update extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            value: '',
            suggestions: [],
            setOfAllBooks: [],
            searchedBooks: []
        };

        this.openBookDetails = this.openBookDetails.bind(this);
        this.setTableData = this.setTableData.bind(this);
    }

    setTableData(searchedBook){
        this.setState({searchedBooks: searchedBook})

        console.log(this.state.searchedBooks)
    }

    openBookDetails(){
        console.log("openBookDetails")
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <Search state={this.state} setTableData={this.setTableData} />
                <Table data={this.state.searchedBooks} action={this.openBookDetails} />
            </div>

        )
    }
}

export default Update;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your TableRow component is a [stateless (presentional) component](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0) so you cannot use `this` inside of it. The openBookDetails function is in the class-component Update so it's not in TableRow but in Table's parent : Update.

You need to pass your openBookDetails function as props from Update to Table then from Table to TableRow